# Twin paradox - how much energy does it take to travel to the future?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, energy-conservation, time-dilation

In the usual twin paradox in Minkowski space, we have twins Alice and Bob. Alice stays at home. Meanwhile, Bob visits a distant planet and returns. On return, Bob has aged less than Alice. So, in a sense, the net effect is that Bob has managed to time travel to the future.
Now, in order to travel to the future, Bob has clearly required an input of energy (to get him up to speed, to reverse his direction of travel, and finally to come to rest upon finding Alice again). Is it possible to calculate the energy which Bob required in order to travel to the future? Does this question even make sense? I am a little unclear on how to think about energy/work done etc in the relativistic context.

As an extension of this question, what about in general relativity? For example, what if Bob knows that there is a Black hole nearby and heads off to put himself into a slingshot trajectory around the black hole. Can one, in principle, calculate how much energy that will require?

Comment: I am not sure this really makes sense. If closed timelike curves really were allowed to exist, something like an averaged energy condition may not hold. I am not sure how to substantiate this statement, but on an all I am not sure that it makes sense to ask how much energy is required to "time travel". On the other hand, one can calculate how much energy it requires to be put into an orbit around a black hole -- this would be no different than usual astrophysics. I am not clear on what the GR version of your question asks.

Comment: If Bob merely "puts himself into stasis" then the energy required will be much less, right? ;)

Comment: Sitting on my couch results in traveling forward in time.

Answer (score 2):

Energy is a frame-variant quantity, while the difference in the age between the two twins is an invariant quantity. An invariant quantity cannot be a function of only a frame-variant quantity, so clearly there would be something missing.

The covariant generalization of energy is the four-momentum. I cannot think* of a useful function of, say, the four-momentum that would do this either. An identical rocket engine with an identical $\Delta v$ can produce more or less "time travel" based on the timing of the burns.

*the fact that I am not aware of something doesn't prove it is impossible, but it does indicate that it is uncommon

Comment: If you want an invariant characterization of a timelike curve, there is *integrated acceleration*: $\int |a|d\tau$. For example for relativistic rocket we have $m_f/m_i<\exp(-\int |a|d\tau) $.